# Hello World Objective-C Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have recently started looking into basic IOS app development I am using the following tutorial online https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHK3oREwVls&list=PLhAWmh1PlbzGrr8PGLvJBtJ7qniLVTQ9E and I seem to have hit a stumbling block, below are my two view controllers. The error I am getting is regarding the displaytext.text section of the view controller M. The error appearing is;

HelloCocoaViewController.m:30:4: Use of undeclared identifier 'displaytext'; did you mean '_displaytext'?

When I make the suggested change I get a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT around the below code.

```
  @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([HelloCocoaAppDelegate class]));
```

Below is my the code I am currently using.

```
//
//  HelloCocoaViewController.h
//  Test
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HelloCocoaViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *displaytext;
- (IBAction)hellobutton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)byebutton:(id)sender;

@end


//
//  HelloCocoaViewController.m
//  Test
//
//

#import "HelloCocoaViewController.h"

@interface HelloCocoaViewController ()

@end

@implementation HelloCocoaViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)hellobutton:(id)sender {
   displaytext.text=@"Hello";

}

- (IBAction)byebutton:(id)sender {
   displaytext.text=@"Bye";
}
@end
```

I will appreciate any and all help.

*Edit: I have now tried to implement the solutions suggested (I hope this is correct) however I am sill experiencing the same SIGABRT issue.*

```
@implementation HelloCocoaViewController
@synthesize displaytext;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)hellobutton:(id)sender {
   self.displaytext.text=@"Hello";

}

- (IBAction)byebutton:(id)sender {
   self.displaytext.text=@"Bye";
}
@end
```

Comment: as far as I know the sigabrt error will always show you that main section of your app, it's a general error but you can see on the left in xcode beneath that caution basically what was happening before the error. I was going to say you need to synthesize your uilabel property but another user caught it so I gave them an upvote. Basically you need a @synthesize displaytext; right below implementation helloCocoaViewController in your .m of your class as well as changing displaytext.text to self.displaytext.text in your code...you'll learn as you progress why, basically unseen methods.

Comment: It's important to learn the ins and outs of debugging.  First you need to learn to set breakpoints in general and how to understand the console log and debug data display.  Then you need to set an exception breakpoint, so that most errors will the caught in a way that allows you to inspect the call stack at the time of error.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) to find out why your app is crashing. Or just review the tutorial and find what you don't understand and what youa re doing wrong (if the app works in the tutorial).

Comment: Thanks for all your help and sources you have provided, I am going to revise over some debugging and see what the issues are, currently I have found: '[<HelloCocoaViewController 0x7580e90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labeldisplay.'    Thank you all again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are not using `@synthesize` to define a backing variable for the property it will implicitly add on as `_<propertyname>`

so either use the property as `self.displaytext` or access the property's backing variable directly via `_displaytext`

---

Since Apple switched the default compiler from GCC to llvm Objective-C evolves very fast. WWDC videos are a great way to keep track of those improvements

- [WWDC 2013: Advances in Objective-C](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/404xbx2xvp1eaaqonr8zokm/404/404-SD.mov?dl=1)
- [WWDC 2012: Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405)